# What is the difference between vfmaq_f32 and vmlaq_f32 in the neon instruction set, and the difference in running speed and accuracy

Tags: c++, arm, arm64, neon

hello，What is the difference between vfmaq_f32 and vmlaq_f32 in the neon instruction set, and the difference in running speed and accuracy

On macOS ARM64, the code runs consistently

```
#include<arm_neon.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    float a = 12.3839467819;
    float b = 21.437678904;
    float c = 4171.42144;
    printf("%.17f\n",a);
    printf("%.17f\n",b);
    printf("%.17f\n",c);


    printf("%.17f\n",a+b*c);

    float32x4_t a_reg = vdupq_n_f32(a);
    float32x4_t b_reg = vdupq_n_f32(b);
    float32x4_t c_reg = vdupq_n_f32(c);
    float32x4_t res_reg = vfmaq_f32(a_reg, b_reg, c_reg);
    float res[4] = {0.f};
    vst1q_f32(res,res_reg);
    printf("%.17f\n",res[0]);


    res_reg = vmlaq_f32(a_reg, b_reg, c_reg);
    vst1q_f32(res,res_reg);
    printf("%.17f\n",res[0]);


    res_reg = vmulq_f32(b_reg, c_reg);
    res_reg = vaddq_f32(res_reg, a_reg);
    vst1q_f32(res,res_reg);
    printf("%.17f\n",res[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include<iostream>
using namespace std;` this can't be tagged with [tag:C].

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0409/g/Instruction-Timing/Instruction-specific-scheduling/Advanced-SIMD-floating-point-instructions?lang=en

Comment: I might be wrong, but it looks like vfmaq_f32() is just an intrinsic alias.

Answer (score 0):

`vfmaq_f32` defined as a single fused operation, whereas `vmlaq_f32` *can* be implemented with a multiply then an accumulate.

Two explanations come to mind.  First, at some point the fused version (the `FMLA` instruction) was possibly an optional instruction (I don't know when, and I'm a bit too lazy to dig through really old documentation).  The second possibility, which seems more likely, is that the fused version may have, at some point, been a bit slower.

These days, it looks like compilers pretty much just [compile both to the same instruction](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:21,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:21,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:8),source:%27%23include+%3Carm_neon.h%3E%0A%0Afloat32x4_t+foo(float32x4_t+a,+float32x4_t+b,+float32x4_t+c)+%7B%0A++++return+vmlaq_f32(a,+b,+c)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afloat32x4_t+bar(float32x4_t+a,+float32x4_t+b,+float32x4_t+c)+%7B%0A++++return+vfmaq_f32(a,+b,+c)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:armv8-clang1701,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:6),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+armv8-a+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) so it's effectively an alias, but you should probably still use `vfmaq_f32` if you want accuracy, but `vmlaq_f32` if you are more interested in speed.